# Create a menu for the Wordpress Starkers theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm fairly new to Wordpress. I'm using the 'naked' Starkers Theme. It's pretty awesome. 
http://starkers.viewportindustries.com/

The only thing I'm not getting is to add a menu or a widget. It says the theme doesn't support custom menus.

Also the theme doesn't have a sidebar. Do I have to add something to the code to make this work?

Maybe someone if familiar with the Starkers theme and could put me in the right direction. Thank you very much. And if this is a dumb question, i'm sorry.

This is the code:

```
  <?php Starkers_Utilities::get_template_parts( array( 'parts/shared/html-header',      'parts/shared/header' ) ); ?>

  <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
  <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
  <?php the_content(); ?>
  <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
  <?php endwhile; ?>

  <?php Starkers_Utilities::get_template_parts( array(    'parts/shared/footer','parts/shared/html-footer' ) ); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add code below into your **functions.php** file to give your theme menu support:

```
register_nav_menu('primary', __('Primary Menu', 'rs'));
```

And add this code into **functions.php** file to add sidebar into your theme.

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
    register_sidebar();
```